# MVC Controller Create New Record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am using c# MVC I am trying to create 2 new records in 2 tables - employee and address table.
I have the following so far:

```
    db.employee.AddObject(empmodel.employee);
    db.address.AddObject(empmodel.address); 
    db.SaveChanges();
```

When an employee record is created, it creates an EmpID record which is autogenerated. I need to get that EmpID and create a new record in the address table with that EmpID as as there is a primary foreign key relationship between the 2 tables.

I am not sure how to get the EmpID from employee table and then create a new record for the address table. I thought I could get it after AddObject but it did not create an employee record.

Comment: Are you doing code first developement? Or are you relying on the EDMX file? If you can provided some mroe details about your EF approach that will help.

Comment: Have you tested this?  If you are using EF, you should be able to just add the empmodel to db.employee and then SaveChanges().  EF will handle creating the address record for you.

Comment: @Maess Only if he has a relationship set up in EF :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're not supposed to just give feedback, but in this case, this answer is right on, no need to go further. If you create a model, using a database table, as long as that database table has an ID field.  It will create the `get/set` methods for you.  In mine, it even created a more elaborate `get/set` method probably because the name of my ID field is ProdID.   But you can expand the `model.cs` file, (after you create the model from the database) and see the `get/set` method these guys are talking about.  In the case you are using a `GUID` you can just use

```
card.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

The `NewGuid()`  method in the controller create function.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using Entity Framework given the code you are providing. You should set up a relationship between your two entities and let EF handle this for you:

```
public class Employee {
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you create the entities:

```
// create a new Employee
Employee employee = new Employee(); 

// create a new Address
Address address = new Address();

// associate the address with the new employee
employee.Address = address;

// add the employee to the data context
db.employee.AddObject(employee);

// when you call save changes, since your Address is attached to your
// employee, it will get added for you and you don't have to add it to the
// context yourself. Entity Framework will save the Employee, get the ID
// from this table and then add a new Address record using the ID that was
// just inserted. 
db.SaveChanges();
```

It will add both objects and add the foreign key for you.

**Edit**

This is a code first example. If you are using Database first using the designer, just set up the relationship using the designer. The code to add the employee shouldn't change in this case.

Comment: I am doing   db.employee.AddObject(empmodel.employee);     db.address.AddObject(empmodel.address);  in one shot as I need to create 2 records in the 2 seperate tables in one shot. How do I get the EmpID from first to enter into second?

Comment: Read my answer please. If you set up a relationship, you don't have to add the child object manually. It gets added to the database for you.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
db.Employees.Add(emp);
db.Savechanges();
```

Go to this link for a complete tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOiwjbPmxSk